# How to assign EIP to Autoscaling Group of VPC in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation

I want to assign one of my reserved Elastic IP's(ec2 classic ip) to Autoscaling group in VPC. Using AWS Cli I moved ip to vpc:

```
$ aws ec2 move-address-to-vpc --public-ip 23.23.23.23
```

And saw in aws concole, that this IP passed to VPC.
And Assigned in tags of AutoscalingGroup in Cloudformation template in Resources:

```
"Process": {
        "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "LaunchConfigurationName": {"Ref": "PreprocessorLC"},
            "LoadBalancerNames": [{"Ref": "ProcessELB"}],
            "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [{ "Fn::Join" : [",", [ { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet1"}, { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet2"} ]]}],
            "AvailabilityZones": {"Ref": "AZs"},
            "MinSize" : "1",
            "MaxSize" : "1",
            "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
            "Tags" : [
                {"Key": "Name", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["", [{"Ref": "Env"}, "-Process"]]}, "PropagateAtLaunch": true},
                {"Key": "WorkersScalingGroup", "Value": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["Offering-", {"Ref": "Env"},  "-Process-Worker"]]}, "PropagateAtLaunch": true},
                {"Key": "EIP", "Value": {"Ref": "ProcessIP"}, "PropagateAtLaunch": true},
                {"Key": "Environment", "Value": {"Ref": "Env"}, "PropagateAtLaunch": true}
            ]
        }
    }
```

And added value of "ProcessIP" in Parameters:

```
"ProcessIP":{
            "Description": "DEV: 23.23.23.23",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "23.23.23.23",
            "AllowedValues": ["23.23.23.23"]
}
```

And it doesn't worked. Still get random IP.
If someone can tell where I'm wrong or what should to add for make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Region in Which instance is running
EC2_REGION='us-east-1'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

#Instance ID captured through Instance meta data
InstanceID=`/usr/bin/curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

#Elastic IP captured through the EIP instance tag
Elastic_IP=`/opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/ec2-describe-tags -O $AWS_ACCESS_KEY -W $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --filter resource-id=$InstanceID --filter key='EIP' | cut -f5`
Allocate_ID=`/opt/aws/apitools/ec2/bin/ec2-describe-tags -O $AWS_ACCESS_KEY -W $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --filter resource-id=$InstanceID --filter key="AllocationID" | cut -f5`

#Assigning Elastic IP to Instance
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $InstanceID --allocation-id $Allocate_ID
```

Comment: There is a discussion about a similar method on the aws forums here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=498761

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I needed to keep a bank of unassigned EIPs and randomly assign them to the EC2 when they boot.  That way I always know my servers will be using a specific list of IPs that I can whitelist in other places.

If you create several EIPs named "prod-pool" you can then use this script.

```
apt install -y jq awscli
ALLOCATION_ID=`aws ec2 describe-addresses --filters="Name=tag:Name,Values=prod-pool" | jq -r '.Addresses[] | "\(.InstanceId) \(.AllocationId)"' | grep null | awk '{print $2}' | xargs shuf -n1 -e`

if [ ! -z $ALLOCATION_ID ]; then
    aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOCATION_ID --allow-reassociation
fi
```

You can attached this policy to your IAM user

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEIPAttachment",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress",
        "ec2:DisassociateAddress"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is newer so doesn't have the reputation, but is IMHO the best as it uses the ability to keep credentials out of the open and pretty easy to apply in a number of automation situations.

Comment: This looks great. however how does it know to associate free IP and not taken one ?

Comment: @Nir There's a `grep null` happening to only select an IP with no assigned `AllocationId`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly associate the Elastic IP address with your desired EC2 instance. You can do this in a userdata script at launch time, or externally through other scripting or Configuration Management.

PropagateAtLaunch simply propagates tags from the Auto Scaling Group to any instances that are launched as a result of Auto Scaling actions. I'm not aware of any magic that would cause a tagged Elastic IP address to be associated with a launched instance.

See more discussion and examples of launch time scripting with EIPs [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=248764).

Comment: Without VPC it works fine to put it in tags. Do you know any "scripting or Configuration Management" example for this specific issue?

Comment: By the way, I'm interested to hear that this works in EC2 Classic. I haven't seen that before. You're sure there's no scripting going on there presumably.

Comment: We worked for more than half year like that. I'm sure, because I wrote that)

Comment: I'm not doubting you; I just haven't seen this. For example, I don't see any documentation relating "PropagateAtLaunch" and "EIP" that indicates that it will cause a launched instance to associate to that EIP. I also don't see how this would work if Auto Scaling launched multiple instances (would the last-launched instance 'win' the EIP?) Point me at any documentation if you have it. Thanks.

Comment: AWS documentation is terrible. Propagate at launch EIP that you put in Parameters, was obviously for my without any examples. Here you can see other examples: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-tags.html And will work only for first instance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a AWS Lambda function which will automatically bind an Elastic IP address from a pool to instance of an autoscaling group. This alleviates the need to grab an EIP address in the bootscript of the instances. For a complete description check out 
 https://binx.io/blog/2019/09/02/how-to-dynamically-bind-elastic-ip-addresses-to-an-auto-scaling-group/