# Creating zookeeper ensemble using cft

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zookeeper

I am facing one problem while automating 3 node  zookeeper ensemble using  cloud formation template.

1. I created a auto scale group with 3 node zookeeper installed from
   userdata.
2. But I want to  change the zoo.cfg  zookeeper ensemble property
   server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
   server.3=zoo3:2888:3888. But in aws I am not sure of
   server.1,server.2,server.3 ip since it is dynamic
3. Because of the above I am not able to  change the config file.
4. To solve I created ENI and got 3 static ip  but not able to attach
   ENI to asg.

Is there any  better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are your nodes in VPC or EC2 classic?

Comment: Ignore my previous question? Why are you not using Elastic IP?

Comment: I wanted to keep ip static hence i create 3  elastic network interface and attach same to ec2 while creating

Comment: You can use Elastic IP address too instead of a ENI. That will be more easy option.

Comment: but can i attach them to autoscaling group .I am creating 3 nodes using cft.Hence I am not finding way to attach these eni when i use autoscale configuration

Comment: I am not familiar with zookeeper but you can attach Elastic IP to EC2 instances in ASG. Check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849360/how-to-assign-eip-to-autoscaling-group-of-vpc-in-cloudformation-template

Comment: Thanks but due to organization constraint i cannot use elastic ip i can  use eni