# Cloud Formation : Assign Elastic IP to Auto Scaling group with one instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I wrote a cloud formation template to create an Auto Scaling group with size as 1. Now I want to assign an elastic IP to this instance via cloud formation.

Unfortunately, AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup doesn't have any Fn::GetAtt to get the instance-id attached to this auto scaling group.

Is there any other way to get the instance-id for this instance? Or can we directly get instance-id of an existing EC2 instance from its Name tag in cloud formation?

Userdata script is not acceptable, as it requires AWS IAM credentials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign EIP to Autoscaling Group of VPC in Cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849360/how-to-assign-eip-to-autoscaling-group-of-vpc-in-cloudformation-template)

Comment: This answer talks about userdata script which is not acceptable, as it requires AWS IAM credentials. We don't expect template users to setup IAM credentials, before using it.

Comment: You don't need IAM credentials for applications running on EC2, you can use IAM roles.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cloudformation to create an instance, assign an EIP and then associated the instance with the ASG. All of this possible in cloudformation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html

> InstanceId
>
> The ID of the Amazon EC2 instance you want to use to create the Auto Scaling group. Use this property if you want to create an Auto Scaling group that uses an existing Amazon EC2 instance instead of a launch configuration.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-instanceid

Edit: This EIP will be lost if the instance scales, A way to guarantee that the EIP stays with the instance is with an userdata script that attaches and an IAM role that has permissions to do so.

Comment: That was my initial plan, to launch an EC2 instance and then attach it to autoscaling group. But I haven't been able to find anything on associating an instance to autoscaling group via cloudformation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-instanceid On passing InstanceId, this copies launch configuration parameters from that instance, and launches a new autoscaling group(and a new instance within it). This doesn't attach the same instance to autoscaling group.

Comment: Yes, it does create a new launch config, and it associates it with the ASG. "When you use an Amazon EC2 instance to create an Auto Scaling group, a new launch configuration is first created and then associated with the Auto Scaling group."

Comment: Are you sure? I tried this now just to double check, and it launches a new instance instead of attaching the provided instance.
This is my resource template
`code`
  {
    "myASG" :
    {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "MinSize" : "0",
        "MaxSize" : "1",
        "DesiredCapacity" : "1",
        "InstanceId" : "i-02a889c736df3f646",
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : [ "subnet-5defa934" ],
      }
    }
`code`

Comment: Did you create a new instance in the cloudformation or ref an instance ID?