# Can't Re-allocate Elastic IP to EC2 Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've tried several methods to re-allocate the elastic iP, but no luck:

- [amazon web services - AWS EC2 User Data script to allocate Elastic IP - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919530/aws-ec2-user-data-script-to-allocate-elastic-ip)
- [Elastic IP in an Auto-Scaling Group | by lakshman sundaram | Medium](https://medium.com/@lakshman301195/elastic-ip-in-an-auto-scaling-group-a43c3bc9e74)

I configured the EC2 Scaling Group to work with Launch Template and Launch Configuration as follows:
min= 1, desired= 1, max= 2.

I have two subnets with same region, but have two different availability zones.

Whenever I terminate an instance, the new instance launches but it doesn't auto receive a Public IP. Even though the settings is set to auto-receive for public IP. Sometimes it has new public ip, but it's different from the one that I wanted.
I'm currently using one Elastic IP.

**User data:**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    INSTANCE_ID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
    MAXWAIT=3
    ALLOC_ID=eipalloc-redacted
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    
    # Make sure the EIP is free
    echo "Checking if EIP with ALLOC_ID[$ALLOC_ID] is free...."
    ISFREE=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $ALLOC_ID --query Addresses[].InstanceId --output text)
    STARTWAIT=$(date +%s)
    while [ ! -z "$ISFREE" ]; do
        if [ "$(($(date +%s) - $STARTWAIT))" -gt $MAXWAIT ]; then
            echo "WARNING: We waited 30 seconds, we're forcing it now."
            ISFREE=""
        else
            echo "Waiting for EIP with ALLOC_ID[$ALLOC_ID] to become free...."
            sleep 3
            ISFREE=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $ALLOC_ID --query Addresses[].InstanceId --output text)
        fi
    done

# Now we can associate the address
echo Running: aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOC_ID --allow-reassociation}
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --allocation-id $ALLOC_ID --allow-reassociation}
```

**Role Policy:**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
            "ec2:AllocateAddress",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:AssociateAddress"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

error:

```
 Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 12 Feb 2021 21:35:16 +0000. Up 21.57 seconds.
Checking if EIP with ALLOC_ID[eipalloc-redacted1234] is free....
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 9: aws: command not found
Running:
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 24: aws: command not found
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 25: aws: command not found
Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 12 Feb 2021 21:35:28 +0000. Up 33.63 seconds.
2021-02-12 21:35:28,823 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2021-02-12 21:35:28,824 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 finished at Fri, 12 Feb 2021 21:35:29 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 34.17 seconds
```

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for errors in your userdata?

Comment: Could you please clarify your actual goal? Do you want the two instances within the Auto Scaling group to both have Elastic IP addresses? If you tell us what you're actually wanting to accomplish (and _WHY_), we might be able to offer additional options. Also, I'm confused that you say "the new instance launches but it doesn't auto receive a Public IP" but you also say "Sometimes it has new public ip" -- so does it receive a Public IP or not? Perhaps you could Edit your question to clarify details? Thanks!

Comment: I configured to have only one instance run at a time, if the cpu reaches at specified percentage, then it will spin up a second instance. Next, after certain time, there is only one instance keep running but with the same Elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
The instance was missing the awscli tool.
Once I installed it, the script is working !
Thanks for the person whom wrote this script.