# Re-Allocate Elastic IP to Compute Engine for Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm seeing that AWS EC2 can be achieved this objective by using a profile and script attaches to the Launch Configuration or Launch Template.
[AWS EC2 User Data script to allocate Elastic IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919530/aws-ec2-user-data-script-to-allocate-elastic-ip)

I'm curious if anybody try to do this on Google Cloud yet ?
If so, please share.

Thanks

Comment: Clearly specify what you are trying to do and the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I want to use an Auto Scaling Group: min: 1, max: 2 instances. If one instance terminated or an additional instance launches, then the new instance would able to reuse the previous instance external IP. I saw another post similar like mine, and the commenter suggested to assign the external IP to the Network Load Balancer (HTTPS) instead the instance.

Comment: Please read this link and then improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have a [MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) with autoscaling you should use [External HTTP(S) Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) load balancer with a [reserved external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) in front of it.